# How to establish database connectivity in Silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight

I am developing a RIA using Silverlight its completely Database Driven Application but I dont know how to establish Database connectivity?

I am using MsSQL database and C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question upto a good extent... so sharing with you all

Check this [link](http://michaelsync.net/2008/03/10/silverlight-2-beta1-database-operations-with-aspnet-web-service-in-silverlight-2) it contains a great set of documentation on using ADO.Net data services in Silverlight.

I found [one more good article](http://silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/sqldatagrid.aspx) so editing my answer.... but its the luck if this works for you if not then author of the article donot respond :( quite sad...

**Here is the [best link](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Video-Learning-CRUD-and-Data-Forms-in-Silverlight-2-Episode-2.aspx) i found hurry!!! It solves the problem.. Lots of thanks to kencox**  the sample is with SQL2008 but i tried it with sql2005 and it worked so You can also try it with MySQL hope it works for you too...

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved in my local machine. But I have one issue. I need to deploy the same application on shared hosting, there is no support provided to handle/install any Service as I have no control over IIS. Any help in this regard most appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends what database you are using, if you're using mysql, you can have a look here:

http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

And get the .NET client.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making an application hosted on the Internet, you don't want the RIA directly accessing the database.  Firewalls make this unfeasible, and it could expose you to dangerous attacks.  Typically, you'll have a web service as an intermediary.  If you really need a more direct connectivity to data, you may want to consider [ADO.NET Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx).